# REACT fetch post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, rest, fetch-api

I have problem with routing post request
I need to build register form and post input from form to mongodb
I made router and post route on server side and it works ok (when I use postman)

//form is required model​

```js
router.route('/').post(function(req,res,next){
 res.send(req.body)
 form.create(
  {"first_name": req.body.first_name,
  "last_name": req.body.last_name
 })
  .then(function(data){ 
  res.send(data);
  console.log(data);
 }).catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
});
```

But I need to fire it form client side, not postman. And here i am lost. I can do it with  but when i add onSubmit action it doesnt work. And I need to use new function to fire another thing without redirecting to another page. How to pass this.refs.first_name.value to body so that i could use fetch function?? 
Below react component

added this JavaScript/JSON snippet

```js
export default class Form extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }
 handleSubmit(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.refs.first_name.value);
  fetch('/', {
   method: 'post',
   body: {
    "first_name": this.refs.first_name.value
   }
  });
 };
 render () {
  return (
   
   <div id="signup">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input ref="first_name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="first_name"/><br />
        <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="last_name"/><br />
       <button type="Submit">Start</button>
    </form>
​
   </div>
​
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess the way you are using `ref` has been deprecated. try below see if you have any luck.

```js
export default class Form extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 handleSubmit(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('/', {
   method: 'post',
   headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
   body: {
    "first_name": this.firstName.value
   }
  });
 };

 render () {
  return (
   
   <div id="signup">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input ref={(ref) => {this.firstName = ref}} placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="first_name"/><br />
        <input ref={(ref) => {this.lastName = ref}} placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="last_name"/><br />
       <button type="Submit">Start</button>
    </form>
​
   </div>
​
  )
 }
}
```

Here is a [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to react docs about `refs`

Comment: Perhaps you are right with way to bind refs. But it's not solution yet. I get only error in server console:
"Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)..."
I in db I see new document with value=0.

Comment: Try `headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},` in fetch see if that helps

Comment: Nope, still the same

Comment: funny part:
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/form', true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(out));

works well

Comment: here you are sending the request to `/form` not `/` and also try using `body: JSON.stringify({
    "first_name": this.firstName.value
   })`

Comment: Headers in fetch need to conform to an interface. Try this: `new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})`. Side note, you should not use refs in that way, use `event.target` for a more consisten behaviour

Comment: `body: JSON.stringify(<insert your data here>)` worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

we need to make sending data as json stringify

```
handleSubmit(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/', {
       method: 'post',
       headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
       body: JSON.stringify({
            "first_name": this.state.firstName
       })
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I made my post request in React.js;

```
const res = fetch('http://15.11.55.3:8040/Device/Movies', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: {
     id: 0,
    },
   })
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     return responseJson.movies;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of controlled components.

For that, add state value,

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.state={ firstname:"", lastname:""} 
}
```

Now input fields to be like,

```
<input placeholder="First Name" type="text" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={(ev)=>this.setState({firstname:ev.target.value})}/>
<input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value={this.state.lastname} onChange={(ev)=>this.setState({lastname:ev.target.value})}/>
```

and handleSubmit should be like,

```
handleSubmit(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('/', {
   method: 'post',
   headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
   body: {
    "first_name": this.state.firstName
   }
  });
 };
```